# total non-disjoined relationship in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

At school we are supposed to create a Model in MySQL Workbench from this ER diagram
[image: ER diagram]

The black arrow means total, non-disjoint relationship.
The definition of that relationship is the following:

> super-entity is always part of one or more sub-entities

I am struggling with creating that model. I found somewhere that there is a way with triggers, but I did not figure out how. I am still a beginner.

Comment: I don't think you can model this in MySQL. You need to create a foreign key from the sub-entities to the super-entity, but that means the super-entity has to be created before you can add it to any of the sub-entities. But if you also have to check that it's part of at least one sub-entity, you have a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: But `FOREIGN KEYs` are not a requirement.

Comment: as @Barmar said, you can not model this ER in MySQL and other relational DBMS. You need something like functions, triggers and stored procedures to handle this total participation.